# How to install PayumModule (ZF2) with Composer

Tags: zend-framework2, payum

Is it possible to install PayumModule via Composer?
If so: which packages have to be declared in composer.json?

I`ve tried to only install the module which is not working:
"payum/payum-module": "dev-master",

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out how it works - maybe it can find a place in the Payum Docs:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "payum/payum": "dev-master",
    "payum/payum-module": "dev-master",
}
```

Comment: payum-module requires payum/core only. It does not have any real payments inside so in order to have them you can install  separately payum/payum which contains all officially supported payments or just the extension you need, for example payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp.

There is a doc on how to start with the module, unfortunatly it misses the section about composer. http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumModule/get-it-started

Comment: I would suggest you to use stable version, current is 0.7 since in dev BC breaks could be introduced at any time before release.

Comment: Thank you! Is there anywhere a more detailed documentation on Payum for ZF2? It´s quite hard to get it up and running after setting up the sandbox solution... No idea how to continue. Does it depend on the requested module?

Comment: that's the all the doc we have for now. you could get some inspiration reading the doc for symfony payum bundle. It is better documented and supports more features. Under the hood both bundle and module use same payum concept